# Minimum repo permissions for a fine-grained GitHub access token such that the user of the token can clone, push, and pull from that repo?

Tags: github, github-token, github-fine-grained-tokens

I wish to adhere to best practice and use a GitHub *fine-grained* token to limit access to a subset of repositories (as opposed to a classic token, which gives access to all repos).

I'd like the token to grant the ability to `git clone`, `git push`, and `git pull` (a little extra is fine, but it should at least allow those capabilities).

Which repository permission(s) do I need to grant?

GitHub presents me a list of available repository permissions options (unfortunately none contain the aforementioned git commands in their descriptions):

[image]

[Fine-grained token permissions documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/authentication/permissions-required-for-fine-grained-personal-access-tokens?apiVersion=2022-11-28) is extremely detailed but I can't spot the answer to my fairly simple question.

#### Note

I don't mind if access to abilities beyond `git clone`, `git push` and `git pull` are also granted; I'm just after some sensible permission/s that grants *at least* those abilities (but doesn't go as far as the classic tokens do). I'm quite confident if every repository permission was granted, then it would allow clone/pull/push, but I wish to avoid going overboard and basically allowing access to every repo permission for that repository - some sensible in-between is what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

- Set `Contents` to `Read and Write`

  - This will *automatically* set `Metadata` to `Read only`

This is all you need to `git clone`, `git push`, and `git pull`.

[image]